# Arabic Letters in python 3.6 for visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, arabic

Any suggestion to make arabic letters appears correctly in python for visual studio 2017, for me it appears like this (????). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding to UTF-8 in Settings Menu.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ! but i'm a beginner and i haven't find in visual studio 2017 where to change the encoding to utf-8 ?

Comment: So the problem was fixed by right click on the top of the windows of the python IDLE, in default/font i change the police to "CourierNew". But the problem now is that the IDE is from the left to the right, or i want to change it from the right to the left.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was fixed by right click on the top of the windows of the python IDLE, in default/font i change the police to "CourierNew". But the letter are from the left to the right , is there any solution to fix that.